# Push gradient image to bottom

Tags: html, css, gradient

On [this page](http://chesapeakerepair.missionmedia.net/service-repair-about) in the left column(header titled, "Service, Repair, About") I have a image(white box with green/yellowish gradient) valigned to the bottom.  Yet is not being pushed all the way to the bottom leaving about 100px in height of white space.

Any tips/suggestion to eliminate that white space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow all of these steps:

- For `#template-content-leftAREA`:

  - Remove `display: block`
  - Remove `float: left`
  - Remove `padding-top: 37px`
  - Change `valign="bottom"` to `valign="top"`
  - Add `background: url(/images/gradient-box.jpg) repeat-x`
- For `.template-leftcontent-bg` inside the `#template-content-leftAREA`:

  - Remove `background: url(/images/gradient-box.jpg) repeat-x`
  - Add `padding-top: 37px`

Following that in Firebug removed the whitespace for me.

Comment: great thank you.   Now to figure out why there is all this space now above the header title?

Comment: You forgot to change `<td valign="bottom" id="template-content-leftAREA">` to `valign="top"`.